# Clicking button to play sound

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, button

I've looked through several answered questions on this website regarding my question but just cannot get this to work.  I'm trying to make a button play a sound once it has been clicked.

Java code:

```
package jg.AvengersSoundboard;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    private Object mp;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    }
}
```

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"  >



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Brain bag full of cats (HULK)"/>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Do you think this madness will end in your rule? (THOR)" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Freedom (LOKI)" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Genius, Playboy, Billionaire. (STARK)" />




<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I have an army, we have a Hulk.  (STARK)" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I put a bullet in my mouth. (HULK)" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I&apos;m bringing the party to you (STARK)" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Last time in Germany (Cpt. America)" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Move away please" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submarine (HULK)" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tell me nobody kissed me (STARK)" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="You mean peace" />


   <Button
       android:id="@+id/Button02"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="55px"
       android:text="Previous"
       android:textSize="18px" >

</Button>
```

Comment: what is the problem now? what is your question? where is your button's click event?

Comment: For that you need to catch button click event in that you can write your code to play audio you have not done anything in this code So how it will play sound.

Answer (score 0):

you need to store the sound file in the res/raw/beep.mp3

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
```

add this on the button click event

```
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
    mp.start();//to start playing the sound
```

to stop that

```
    mp.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create an Object of your button using your button id from you XML 
file like this :

```
Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button two = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button zero = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

...same for others...

Now create a Instance variable of `media player` like this :

```
MediaPlayer mp;
```

now on your `OnCreate` method write this :

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mamacita_zero/*Your Sound file in raw folder*/);
```

Now set a onClickListener for your button :

```
zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

on each button you can use the same approach to play sound.